# Do they make variable isolation transformers?

Tags: transformer, safety, isolation

As I start to set up my work bench, I've been looking at various isolation transformers, and I wondered if they have ones that use a variac as a secondary? 
I know variacs are autotransformers so it's just one winding, but couldnt that mechanism be implemented as a secondary winding in a regular transformer? In other words it would be a 1:1 transformer with an adjustable variable center-tap? Thanks!

Comment: So what great thing does that achieve? An idea without a purpose is just an idea.

Comment: The great thing is the combination of ISOLATION with VARIABLE OUTPUT.  Else you must use a separate iso transformer and variac.

Comment: Richard Crowley is correct, I can get isolation and a variable A/C source in one package as opposed to two separate, large, expensive unit. Just do a google search on how much isolation transformers cost and how much variable autotransformers cost and you'll get an answer on what the purpose is.

Comment: The subject title is confusing - the question sounds as if it is asking for a center tap transformer with the ability to adjust the center (e.g. to be 60:40 rather than 50:50). Is that what you are asking for or is it an isolating Variac?

Comment: The title is clearly wrong. If it is "variable" then it isn't necessarily "CENTER-tapped" and vice-versa.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to electronics. I was asking if what I know now is an isolated variac exists. I see how the term center tap was not appropriate considering the wording under the question and what I was looking for (which was isolation and variable voltage in one package). I edited the question.

Answer (score 5):

You must be thinking about [an isolated variac](http://www.radioelectricindia.com/isolateddw.htm)

[image]